# In Eclipse PyDev is there a way to exclude arbitrary file-types from the Pydev Package explorer?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

If you click on the icon resembling a downard-pointing triangle in the PyDev Package Explorer and then select "Customize View", The "Available Customizations" pop-down allows the user to select which of a standard set of files are visible in the package explorer.

That's great if you wish to exlude or include certain standard types of file from the view, however I'd like to exclude a type which is currently unknown to PyDev.

In this case, I'd like to exclude "*,cover" - that's any automatically generated coverage report file. PyDev creates these files any time you try to run a coverage analysis but does not seem to have a way of excluding these files from the views. I'd love to hide all the ",cover" files in order to reduce the clutter in my package explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the left of the down arrow is the "Setup custom filters" button. You can enter custom filters delimited by commas. If that file name indeed has a comma in it, then you will have to enter the filter as `*cover` since `*,cover` is treated as two separate filters.